# Marker Model Theory Lemma 4.3.40: How does the implication follow?

Tags: proof-explanation, model-theory

[image]

For brevity, I omitted the proof of the claim. The [] notation indicates the basic open set in the stone space over M that the formula determines. The bar notation indicates a finite sequence of variables or elements. The red arrow indicates the implication that I suspect Marker used in the step.

However, I am not sure how it follows. I agree that the number of types containing phi(v) is greater than or equal to aleph_1. But not all of these types need to be realized in M, so why should the number of elements in x in M that cause phi(x) to be true be greater than or equal to aleph_1?

Moreover, why does it say "by choice of p"? I don't see why the choice of p is useful for that particular step.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this answer is the argument that Marker had in mind, but it works anyway. If you replace $[ \phi(v) ]$ throughout by $\{x \in M : \phi(x)\}$ (and similarly for other uses of $[ \; ]$, like $[\phi(v) \land \psi(v)]$), then the entire argument (including the claim) still works. So instead of working with opens in the Stone space, you simply work directly with the sets of realisations in $M$.

The Stone space itself is used nowhere, so I suspect that this may actually be the 'right' argument. At least it is more transparent.

The bit "By choice of $p$" refers to the fact that $|\{x \in M : \phi(x) \land \neg(\delta_0(x) \land \ldots \land \delta_n(x))\}| \leq \aleph_0$.

Comment: my fault, I mislead you by omitting the proof of the claim. The proof of the claim itself uses compactness of stone space as well as the definition of omega stability based on the number of types. So I don't think this is resolvable by taking that approach

Comment: @kyary I read the claim as well (got a copy of the book), and that is why I said "(including the claim)" in my answer. You do this in exactly the same way as described in the proof, just replace $[\phi_\sigma]$ by $\{x \in M : \phi_\sigma(x)\}$. Then the argument using compactness and stability is as follows: every branch in the tree determines a type (by compactness), and since every pair of branches together is inconsistent we get at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ many types, contradicting $\omega$-stability.

Comment: I agree with Mark that the correct way to prove this is by looking at definable subsets of $M$ rather than subsets of the Stone space throughout.